# Cannot use Font Awesome 6

Tags: unicode, fontawesome

I'm trying to setup Font Awesome 6 on Overleaf but I'm failing.
Although Font Awesome 5 is available as a package, version 6 is not.

I installed the fonts manually by downloading the `.otf` files from [Font Awesome website](https://fontawesome.com/docs/desktop/setup/get-started) and uploading them to Overleaf, and set the preamble of my document to look like this (using XeLaTeX)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{Font Awesome 6 Free-Regular-400.otf}
```

Fairly straightforward, expect that now I don't know how to reference the specific icon that I want.

I've tried to reference it based on its unicode character, as provided in the [Font Awesome icon search](https://fontawesome.com/search).
For instance, to try to render the house icon I write

```latex
{\FA \char"f11b}
```

and get the error

```
<to be read again> 
                   f
l.7 {\FA \char"f
                11b}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Missing character: There is no ^^@ (U+0000) in font [Font Awesome 6 Free-Regular-400.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;!
[1
```

Is there something basic missing?
Should I be writing the unicode character in a different way?
It's quite unfortunate not to see a Font Awesome 6 package for LaTex, I search everywhere and came out empty handed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hex digits using `"` have to be uppercase. `\char"F11B\relax`

Specifically house is at F015 in the Solid not Regular font (the zip file includes three OTF Files covering different ranges)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path=./]{Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf}

\begin{document}

1: {\FA \char"F11B}

2: {\FA \char"F015}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. It does seem to fix the error, but it still shows a square box. Any ideas why? Also, could you elaborate on the need for the `\relax`?

Comment: @JoséFerreira you don't need the `\relax` if you have `}` as you show, but if you have `\def\foo{\char"F11B}`  the number isn't terminated so `\foo 123` would try to access position  hex F11B123 .  The correct latex version is `\symbol{"F11B}` (which adds `\relax` for you)  I do not have the font, are you sure it has a character in that slot?

Comment: @JoséFerreira house seems to be  F015 / https://fontawesome.com/icons/house?s=solid&f=classic

Comment: @JoséFerreira see update

Comment: Yup, you are correct, it was the wrong character. I will mark your answer as solution. Thanks!